# 3個以上の値を使うObjectAnimatorをXMLで書くことはできますか？

Tags: android, android-animation

Viewに下記のようなアニメーションを実装しています。(translationYが 0 → 100 → 0 → -100 → 0 と変化するのを繰り返します)

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0, 100, 0, -100, 0);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setDuration(5000);
anim.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
anim.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
anim.start();
```

できればアニメーションはなるべくXMLで指定したいのですが、このように5個の値を経由するアニメーションを`res/animator/`下のXMLで作成することはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sequentially な set の中に複数の objectAnimator を含めることで実現可能ではあります。
ただ、以下サンプルを見ると分かると思いますが、非常に冗長です。自分だったら Java コードで済ませるかな、と思います。

(XML側：res/animator/y5.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:ordering="sequentially">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:valueFrom="0" android:valueTo="100"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:duration="1250" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:duration="1250" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:valueTo="-100"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:duration="1250" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationY"
        android:duration="1250" />
</set>
```

(Java側)

```
Animator anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.y5);
anim.setTarget(view);
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
    @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) { }
    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) { }
    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        animation.start();
    }
    @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) { }
});
anim.start();
```

XML側のsetにrepeatCountを設定することができないのと、
AnimatorにもまたrepeatCountを設定するメソッドが無いので、
自前でイベントを捕捉してループを実現しています。